# Unsure if association is working in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

My app has users and users are able to post links to my app. I have an association set up so that a user `has many :links` and links `belong_to` a user (see below for models). Now I am trying to get the users email to appear in the show template and I am getting a nil value for Link.user for new links. Can someone maybe shed some light as to why? Is my association incorrect? The user has been logged in when posting links.

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :links
    acts_as_voter
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

Link model:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    acts_as_votable

    attr_accessor :avatar
    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(@link.created_at) %> by <%= @link.user.try(:email) %>
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "links", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end
```

Link creation in Links controller;

```
  def new
    @link = Link.new
  end

  def create
    @link = Link.new(link_params)

    if @link.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def link_params
      params.require(:link).permit(:title, :url, :avatar)
    end
```

Comment: How does `users` and `links` tables look? Is there user_id column in links table?

Comment: I posted my schema for links and users. Yes there is a user ID in the links table @archana

Comment: Definitely check the associations using the console to make sure the records are being created correctly. See my answer below.

Comment: Please also show us the code for `Link` creation.

Comment: I just added my controller actions for creating a link @JohannesThorn

Comment: Your `link_params` does not mention `user_id` so in the new `@link` there is no `user` set. You need to set the corresponding user manually it won't be set by the framework only because a user is logged in.

Comment: I changed my link_params to permit user_id, but the issue continues to persist @JohannesThorn

Comment: Do you post a user ID? Otherwise you need to set the user by `@link.user = find_logged_in_user` where `find_logged_in_user` determines the current logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the links are actually being assigned to a user when created.

Using the rails console. Try looping through the links and making sure they have user_ids:

in the rails console:

```
ap Link.all.map(&:user)
```

If they are indeed owned by a user

```
<%= @link.user.email %>
```

should print out the email.

You should be able to do something like this in your controller:

```
@user.links << params[:new_link]
```

Make sure that much is working.

Answer (score 0):

You are using devise.  Inside your Link controller, you have to authenticate your logged on user.

```
# app/controllers/links_controller.rb
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @link = current_user.links.new(link_params)
    if @link.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'  # generally this is a render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

I truncated the file here.  Please read the [devise manual](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)